# Can a hyper-threaded processor core execute two threads at the exact same time?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, cpu-architecture, hyperthreading

I'm having a hard time understanding hyper-threading. If the logical core doesn't actually exist, what's the point of using hyper-threading?. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) article states that:

> For each processor core that is physically present, the operating system addresses two virtual (logical) cores and shares the workload between them when possible.

If the two logical cores share the same execution unit, that means one of the threads will have to be put on hold while the other executes, that being said, I don't understand how hyper-threading can be useful, since you're not actually introducing a new execution unit. I can't wrap my head around this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [my answer on a softwareengineering.SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024) for some details about how modern CPUs find and exploit [instruction-level parallelism (ILP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) by running multiple instructions at once.  (Including a block diagram of Intel Haswell's pipeline, and links to more CPU microarchitecture details).  Also [**Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!**](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/)

You have a CPU with lots of execution units and a front-end that can keep them mostly supplied with work to do, but only under good conditions.  Stalls like cache misses or branch mispredicts, or just limited parallelism (e.g. a loop that does one long chain of FP additions, bottlenecking on FP latency at one (scalar or SIMD) add per 4 or 5 clocks instead of one or two *per* clock) will result in throughput of much less than 4 instructions per cycle, and leave execution units idle.

**The point of HT (and [Simultaneous Multithreading (SMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) in general) is to keep those hungry execution units fed with work to do, even when running code with low ILP or lots of stalls** (cache misses / branch mispredicts).

SMT only adds a bit of extra logic to the pipeline so it can keep track of two separate architectural contexts at the same time.  So it costs a lot less die area and power than having twice or 4x as many full cores.  (Knight's Landing Xeon Phi runs 4 threads per core, mainstream Intel CPUs run 2.  Some non-x86 chips run 8 threads per core, aimed at database-server type workloads.)  But of course having to divide out-of-order execution resources between logical threads often means the throughput gain is significantly below 2x or 4x, often far below, and for some workloads is negative.

Also related *[What is the difference between Hyperthreading and Multithreading? Does AMD Zen use either?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74152562)* - AMD's SMT is basically the same as Intel's, just not using the trademark "Hyperthreading" for it.  See also other links in my answer there, like https://www.realworldtech.com/nehalem/3/ and especially **https://www.realworldtech.com/alpha-ev8-smt/** for an intro with diagrams to what SMT is all about.  (Many members of the Alpha EV8 design team was hired by Intel after DEC folded, and went on to implement SMT in Netburst (Pentium 4) which Intel branded Hyperthreading.)

---

#### Common misconceptions

Hyperthreading is *not* just optimized context switching.  Simpler designs that switch to the other thread on a cache miss are possible, but HT is more advanced than that.  (Switch-on-stall, or round-robin "barrel processor").

With two threads active, the front-end alternates between threads every cycle (in the fetch, decode, and issue/rename stages), but **the out-of-order back-end can actually execute uops from both logical cores in the same cycle**.  The issue/rename stage is 4 uops wide on Intel before Ice Lake.

In pipeline stages that normally alternate, any time one thread is stalled, the other thread gets all the cycles in that stage.  HT is much better than just fixed alternating, because one thread can get lots of work done while the other is recovering from a branch mispredict or waiting for a cache miss.

Note that up to 10 or 12 cache misses can be outstanding at once (from L1D cache in Intel CPUs: this is the number of LFB (Line Fill Buffers), and memory requests are pipelined.  But if the address for the next load depends on an earlier load (e.g. pointer chasing through a tree or linked list), the CPU doesn't know where to load from and can't keep multiple requests in flight.  So it is actually useful for both threads to be waiting on cache misses in parallel.

Some resources are statically partitioned when two threads are active, some are competitively shared.  See [this pdf of slides](https://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234267/Winter2015-2016/ho/WCFiles/L11_core_uarch_2015.pdf#page=34) for some details.  (For more details about how to actually optimize asm for Intel and AMD CPUs, see [Agner Fog's microarchitecture PDF](http://agner.org/optimize/).)

---

When one logical core "sleeps" (i.e. the kernel runs a `HLT` instruction or whatever `MWAIT` to enter a deeper sleep), the physical core transitions to single-thread mode and lets the still-active logical core have all the resources (including the full ReOrder Buffer size, and other statically-partitioned resources), so it's ability to find and exploit ILP in the single thread still running increases more than when the other thread is simply stalled on a cache miss.

---

BTW, some workloads actually run slower with HT.  If your working set barely fits in L2 or L1D cache, then running two on the same core will lead to a lot more cache misses.  For very well-tuned high-throughput code that can already keep the execution units saturated
(like an optimized matrix multiply in high-performance computing), it can make sense to disable HT.  Always benchmark.

On Skylake, I've found that video encoding (with x265 `-preset slower`, 1080p) is about 15% faster with 8 threads instead of 4, on my quad-core i7-6700k.  I didn't actually disable HT for the 4-thread test, but Linux's scheduler is good at not bouncing threads around and running threads on separate physical cores when there are enough to go around.  A 15% speedup is pretty good considering that x265 has a lot of hand-written asm and runs very high instructions-per-cycle even when it has a whole core to itself.  (Slower presets like I used tend to be more CPU-bound than memory-bound.)